# Invalid MEX-file '<myfile>.mexw64': <myfile>.mexw64 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: visual-studio, matlab, opencv, mex

While trying to run [opencv sample matlab call](http://xanthippi.ceid.upatras.gr/people/evangelidis/matlab_opencv/data/), I am getting an error

Invalid MEX-file 'mypath\displayImage.mexw64': mypath\displayImage.mexw64 is not a valid Win32 application.

There are no errors while compiling. Also there are no errors while compiling and running simple helloworld sample.

What can be a reason for this? Why it expects win32 when even filename says 64?

Matlab is 2013a, VS is 2012, both are 64bit.

**UPDATE**

I found [this "solution"](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-36Z527/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-36Z527) of year 2009 saying that any of called DLLs should be 64 bit.

Is this

(1) true nowadays, and

(2) possible in practice?

How to check if some called library is 32bit?

Comment: the opencv version libraries you link against are 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: I think yes. I set `LIB` variable to `opencv\build\x64\vc11\lib`. How to check?

Comment: try using [dependancy walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

Comment: Yes, but what to walk from? `Matlab.exe`? :)

Comment: can you walk from the mex file?

Comment: Yes just got it myself. And found that all used opencv dlls are 32bit. Why?

Comment: `mex -v` and see where your library path points to.

Comment: @SuzanCioc: probably off-topic, but let me suggest mexopencv: https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv

Comment: @SuzanCioc: you should post the solution you found as an answer and mark it accepted (you [can](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) do that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok my `PATH` was pointing to `%OPENCV_DIR%\build\x86\vc11\bin` and this was overriding any `LIB` settings.

This was at runtime.

I.e. when I fixed `PATH` value, program started to run even without recompiling.